# excel 2016: how to allow different users to edit different range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-2016

How to allow different users (`John`, `Paul` and `Mika`) to edit different cells in worksheet ?

- `John` is to edit only cells `A2` to `C5` (RANGE 1)
- `Mika` is to edit only cells `E2` to `G5` (RANGE 2)
- `Paul` is to edit only cells `H2` to `K5` (RANGE 3)

In `'allow users to edit ranges'`, I created 3 ranges for above cells with no password. Each range contains the user name permission.

When I select `range 1`, then the `allow users to edit ranges` option is `disabled`.
I'm not able to do apply same for other 2 users...

---

Can someone please help and provide the right steps / vba code?

Comment: I am sorry to tell you but Excel offers little to no security once you allow someone to open an Excel file for editing. Of course, you could code something with VBA and capture all change events on all relevant sheets and afterwards set a password on the VBA code. But this will only work if the user enables VBA. If you want really security then get a database server as a back-end (possibly MSSQL). If that's not an option then I'd make several different Excel files and assign permissions on the files. Other than that you can try several things but will never get any real security; just attempts

Comment: can we force cells locked for a specific users??

Answer (score 0):

In the workbook_beforeclose event we lock all cells. In the workbook.open event we obtain the user's logon name and selectively unlock the desired range for that logon.
If the user doesn't enable macros then everything is protected, if they do enable then only the desired range is available. (You must close the spreadsheet yourself once for the protection to take effect). This assumes a corporate environment in which logging on is enforced. This code goes into the workbook module:

```
Option Explicit
Const pword = "your password here"
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
ws.Unprotect pword
ws.UsedRange.Locked = True
ws.Protect pword
Next ws
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim LogonName As String
LogonName = Environ("UserName")
Dim rangetoedit As Range
Select Case LogonName
Case "John"
    Set rangetoedit = Worksheets(1).Range("A2:C5")
Case "Paul"
    Set rangetoedit = Worksheets(1).Range("H2:K5")
Case "Mika"
    Set rangetoedit = Worksheets(1).Range("E2:G5")
End Select
Worksheets(1).Unprotect pword
rangetoedit.Locked = False
Worksheets(1).Protect pword

End Sub
```

You will want to password protect your vba code as well

Comment: Have you ever downloaded [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) and opened your "secure" file with any other non-Excel application? This software does not much care about your VBA password (just like many other non-Excel applications which still allow editing Excel files). Also, what happens if the file gets force-closed (because Excel crashes or there is an outage)? What happens if I do not enable VBA? I don't want to be overly critical. I am just saying there is pretty sizable hole in "security" as offered above.

Comment: Usually in a corporate environment "security" is designed to prevent errors and accidents, not defend against hackers. And no one can download anything in such an environment, so open office is not an issue. And malicious activities would result in dismissal. You're right about force-crash though - it would be better to have the open routine repeat the close routine first before unlocking the correct region